# SQL query for selecting value with DISTINCT and only one value posted lastly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with selecting only one value posted by one user.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(zprava.id_prijemce),
    uzivatele.jmeno,
    uzivatele.prijmeni,
    zprava.zobrazeno
FROM zprava
INNER JOIN uzivatele
    ON zprava.id_prijemce = uzivatele.id
WHERE id_uzivatele = $id_uzivatele
ORDER BY datum DESC
```

This is what I get:

```
id_prijemce | jmeno  | prijmeni | zobrazeno
31          | Michal | Harych   | 0
31          | Michal | Harych   | 1
35          | Karel  | Pepík    | 0
```

This is what I need to get:

```
id_prijemce | jmeno  | prijmeni | zobrazeno
31          | Michal | Harych   | 1
35          | Karel  | Pepík    | 0
```

I need not to get the row with higher value of "zobrazeno", but the latest posted, so it can be also 0.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Please post the table definitions for `zprava` and `uzivatele`.

Comment: Now I think the query is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to identify the latest record in the `zprava` table, the join this back to `zprava` and to `uzivatele` to obtain the results you want.

```
SELECT
    t1.id_prijemce,
    t3.jmeno,
    t3.prijmeni,
    t1.zobrazeno
FROM zprava t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id_prijemce, MAX(datum) AS max_datum
    FROM zprava
    GROUP BY id_prijemce
) t2
    ON t1.id_prijemce = t2.id_prijemce AND
       t1.datum       = t2.max_datum
INNER JOIN uzivatele t3
    ON t1.id_prijemce = t3.id
WHERE t1.id_uzivatele = $id_uzivatele
ORDER BY t1.datum DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need the MAX value, but the latest inserted value into `zobrazeno`.

Comment: @RadekHomola I know...I saw after I posted, I have updated.  Use a subquery to find the latest date and then join.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't2.jmeno' in 'field list'

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't3.id_uzivatele' in 'where clause'

Comment: To which table does the `id_uzivatele` column belong?

Comment: It's connected with `uzivatele` table in `zpravy`

Comment: It's connected with uzivatele table in zprava